# Extracting a (sub)string from within parentheses

Tags: regex, windows, vbscript, substring

I'm trying to extract text from within parentheses inside of a string. Example:

```
"John D Wilson(some text)"
```

I want to extract only `some text` from the string.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
temp = workingValue
rawname=split(temp)
dim value
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
myRegExp.Global = True

myRegExp.Pattern = "/\([a-z]+\)/"
msgbox temp
if myRegExp.Test(temp)then
value = myRegExp.Replace(temp,"")
msgbox value
else
msgbox "no match"
end if
```

Comment: Note that the solution you accepted `"/\((.*?)\)/` will match the hlilted text in: "John D Wilson(`some text(here(and((here`)not)here)there)". If there are nestings of parenthesis that you need to capture its contents, you will need a solution that does recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a group you can extract the text between parentheses as a submatch. Your pattern won't work, though, because your sample text contains whitespace, but your pattern doesn't. Try something like this:

```
myRegExp.Pattern = "/\((.*?)\)/"
For Each m In myRegExp.Execute(temp)
  value = m.SubMatches(0)
Next

If IsEmpty(value) Then
  MsgBox "no match"
Else
  MsgBox value
End If
```

Regular expression breakdown:

- `\(...\)` matches the enclosing parentheses.
- `.*?` is a non-greedy match for any character except newlines.
- `(...)` is a capturing group, so the non-greedy match can be accessed as a submatch.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex won't match the space in `some text`
Also, you need to put capture groups around just the text if you
want to separate/extract only that text.

One of these might work

`\(([^()]+)\)`

`\(([a-z]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)*)\)/`

`\(([a-zA-Z\s]+)\)`